# How to build a path with a base path and relative path?

Tags: scala, file

Suppose I am writing a function to build a file path given a base path and relative path like that:

```
def buildPath(basePath: String, relativePath: String) = ???

buildPath("a/b/c/d", "x")          // a/b/c/x
buildPath("a/b/c/d", "../../x")    // a/x
buildPath("a/b/c/d", "../../../x") // x
buildPath("a/b/c/d", "../e/x")     // a/b/c/e/x
```

I can write `buildPath` using `java.io.File`:

```
def buildPath(basePath: String, relativePath: String): String = {
  val baseFile = new java.io.File(basePath)
  val toRemove = baseFile.getAbsolutePath.dropRight(baseFile.getPath.length)
  val file = new java.io.File(baseFile.getParentFile, relativePath)
  file.getCanonicalPath.drop(toRemove.length)
}
```

This implementation works but looks ugly. How would you improve it ?

Comment: Afaik, "a/b/c/d/../e/x" is a valid Path, so I would just do basePath+relativePath and be done with it !

Comment: Yes, "a/b/c/d/../e/x" is valid but I _do need_ to canonize it (for some internal reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new java.io.File("/" + basePath, relativePath).getCanonicalPath`

Comment: Does not always work as required. `new java.io.File("a/b/c/d" +  "../e/x").getCanonicalPath` returns `/Users/michael/a/b/c/d../e/x` in my case.

Comment: Your snippet isn't what I suggested ... look closely :)

Comment: It does work as required. I mean _my_ code does. Yours doesn't :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now I see it.

Comment: `new java.io.File("a/b/c/d", "../e/x").getCanonicalPath` returns `/Users/michael/a/b/c/e/x` instead of `a/b/c/e/x`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Michael prepend a slash to the base (it's ok if there's more than one) . I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks (and you probably need to drop the slash like this: `new java.io.File("/" + basePath, relativePath).getCanonicalPath.drop(1)`)